# Банальная организация вывода страниц (PHP фреймворки)

Tags: php, yii2, laravel, framework, шаблоны-проектирования

Как организовать вывод страниц типа Главная, Портфолио, Контакты... (что-то общее и что-то на этих страницах отличается) на любом популярном фреймворке?

Возможно необходимо применить какой-то шаблон проектирования?!

Чтобы не писать типа (понимаю, что это тупо):

```
class Pages extends BaseController {

    public function display($url)
    { 
        switch($url) {  
            case 'index':
            //...
            case 'portfolio':
            //...
            case 'contacts':
            //...
     }
}
```

Comment: Дак а вы пробовали смотреть документацию/примеры к "любому популярному фреймворку"? Возьмите yii2-basic шаблон из документации про скачивание, там будет пример ровно с перечисленными вами страницами. Во фреймворках в плане таких базовых потребностей все уже решено за вас, остается только следовать соглашениям.

Comment: Вроде бы в любом существующем фреймворке можно через CRUD за 5 минут сгенерить такие страницы. А у некоторых в базовой комплектации уже содержатся. Берите один из популярных типа yii2 и ставьте. Всё уже сделано за вас

Comment: вот как выглядит yii2 basic сразу после установки  http://loco.ru/uploads/images/2014/yii2-basic.png

Comment: То есть создавать функцию под каждую станицу? - public function actionAbout(), public function actionContact().... А если таких страниц нужно с 10 или больше - создаем 10-20 функций?

Answer (score 1):

Для банального вывода страниц в принципе фреймворк и не нужен.

Если у Вас есть желание все таки применить его, то вы должны обладать знаниями о Классах, их методах и свойствах, наследовании классов.

На счет паттернов. Есть такой паттерн MVC. Прочитайте что это такое, прежде чем приступать к работе с фреймворками.

И не успокаивайтесь, пока до конца не разберетесь что это такое.

Затем Вам стоит узнать, что все (очень большое кол-во) популярных фрейворков используют этот паттерн проектирования.

И так, вы все это осознали, тогда айда писать свой код с помощью фреймворка [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/).

На мой взгляд, он лучший для новичков в сфере ООП. Есть [русская документация](http://code-igniter.ru/) к нему.

Обязательно проделайте самостоятельно все, что в разделе [Tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html)
В его числе разделы Static pages, News section, Create new items, Conclusion.

Не пугайтесь английского языка. Если с ним трудности, просто переведите страницу, но эти разделы Вы должны в обязательном порядке проделать и понять. Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Вы спрашиваете про Yii и Laravel. На счет Yii не скажу, но в Laravel 5 вы создаете роуты (routes) для каждой страницы. Если не хочется делать контроллеры для каждой страницы, можете сразу в routes вызывать нужный view.

```
Route::get('contactus', function () {
    return view('contactus', ['var' => 'someContent']);
});
```

Дальше создаете один главный view с общими элементами (шапка, меню, футер) и view для каждой странички, который будет содержать только отличающийся контент. Каждый из этих view будет наследовать главный view.

Пример главного шаблона resources/views/main.blade.php

```
<html>

...

@yield('content')

...
</html>
```

Пример шаблона страницы контактов resources/views/contactus.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')
    <h1>Контакты компании</h1>
    ...
@endsection
```